# Dangling or not

Tags: dangling-participles

> "We've been invited to Rachel and Jamie's wedding - speaking of which,
>   did you know that they're moving to Ealing?"

An example from Cambridge Dictionary.

Is the present participle 'speaking' a dangling modifier here? If not, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Speaking of which," is a set phrase and an interjection or interpolated remark. It is not a dangling modifier.

It has the meaning of "with regard to or in relation to what has just been mentioned,"